# My DataTables date range filter using jQuery UI Datepicker works only in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I feel like I could use another pair of eyes on my code right now.

I am using jQuery UI's Datepicker to grab dates from two html inputs:

```
<!-- HTML inputs -->
<p id="date_filter">
    <span id="date-label-from" class="date-label"><?php echo LANG_FROMDATE; ?>: </span><input class="date_range_filter date" type="text" id="datepicker_min" /><img id="calender-from" class="datepicker-calender" src="includes/js/jquery/jquery-ui/img/calendar.png" width="17px" height="18px" />
    <span id="date-label-to" class="date-label"><?php echo LANG_TODATE; ?>: </span><input class="date_range_filter date" type="text" id="datepicker_max" /><img id="calender-to" class="datepicker-calender" src="includes/js/jquery/jquery-ui/img/calendar.png" width="17px" height="18px" />
    <button class="btn" id="reset_btn"><?php echo LANG_RESET; ?></button>
</p>
```

That calender img tag is just an icon that also triggers the datepicker, i.e. like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calender-from').click(function() {
        $("#datepicker_min").datepicker("show");
    });
    $('#calender-to').click(function() {
        $("#datepicker_max").datepicker("show");
    });
});
```

So that's the basic stuff that's all good. The issue I'm having is I have written javascript that is an extension to the DataTables filtering api. I wrote my code based on this example: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

The problem is right now my code is only working in Google Chrome and fails in FireFox, Safari, and Internet Explorer. I probably am just missing something small or have some minor semantic mistake in my code.

I extend the DataTables filtering API like this:

```
// Date range filter
var minDateFilter = "";
var maxDateFilter = "";

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        if ( typeof aData._date == 'undefined' ) {
            aData._date = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
        }

        if ( minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter) ) {
            if ( aData._date < minDateFilter ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ( maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter) ) {
            if ( aData._date > maxDateFilter ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
);
```

This way seems to return false in other browsers because I will get a result of "Showing 1 - 50 of 67 records" regardless of what data I have in the datapicker inputs.

I'm handling the jQuery UI Datepicker inputs like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker_min").datepicker({
        "onSelect": function(date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });

    $( "#datepicker_max" ).datepicker( {
        "onSelect": function(date) {
            maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
    }).keyup(function(){
        maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        oTable.fnDraw();
    });
});
```

I also tried extending the filter API like this (to be closer to original DataTables example):

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var iMin = minDateFilter;
        var iMax = maxDateFilter;
        var iDate = new Date(aData[0]).getTime();
        if ( iMin == "" && iMax == "" )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin == "" && iDate < iMax )
        {
            console.log("iDate 1 = "+iDate);
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin < iDate && "" == iMax )
        {
            console.log("iDate 2 = "+iDate);
            return true;
        }
        else if ( iMin < iDate && iDate < iMax )
        {
            console.log("iDate = 3 "+iDate);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
```

When I do it this way I get a somewhat similar result of my filter code working correctly only in Chrome, and in the other browsers I'll get a result of "Showing 0 to 0 records (filtered from 67 total records)" so here it returns true but it filters incorrectly - i.e. it shows 0 results after filtering regardless of what values are in the datepicker inputs.

Ugh! why is my code only working in Google Chrome and not working in other browsers (Safari, IE, FireFox)?? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: At first I thought it was a var scope isssue with where I originally define minDateFilter and maxDateFilter but moving the code all to the same jquery .ready context just gives me the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this time I actually finally found out what causes this issue.

**Turns out it is an issue with javascript date time objects being *parsed* differently in different browsers**.

So, in order to make your filters fully cross browser friendly, you just need to use date format in your jQuery UI datepicker that works for all broswers to parse dates from using JS `new Date(date_var)`. But that's easier said than done. What I do is manipulate the date time value before sending it through the custom Datatables filter.

See below for the most recent cross browser implementation I've made. It's overall a better implementation than what is in my question because you don't need to worry as much about the filtering api extension it is handled automatically by the function. **See the comments in the code itself for an example where I manipulate the date format to work nicely in Safari's** `date.parse(dateString)` **syntax**.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    // define vars
    var dTable = $('#transactions'),
        date_from = null,
        date_to = null,
        dateRangeFromSearchBox = $('#date_from_range_search'),
        dateRangeToSearchBox = $('#date_to_range_search'),
        dateRangeResetButton = $('#date_range_reset_button');

    // bootstrap our datatable
    dTable.DataTable();

    // bootstrap datepickers
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function (date) {
            date_from = new Date( dateRangeFromSearchBox.val() ).getTime();
            date_to = new Date( dateRangeToSearchBox.val() ).getTime();
            // force change event
            dateRangeFromSearchBox.trigger('change');
            dateRangeToSearchBox.trigger('change');
            // disable further if filtering occured
            if (!isNaN(date_from) &&
                !isNaN(date_from) &&
                dateRangeFromSearchBox.val().length > 0 &&
                dateRangeToSearchBox.val().length > 0) {
                    dateRangeFromSearchBox.prop('disabled', true);
                    dateRangeToSearchBox.prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
    });

    // date range search
    // date from
    dateRangeFromSearchBox.change( function () {
        if (date_from === "" ||
            date_to === "" ||
            dateRangeFromSearchBox.val().length === 0 ||
            dateRangeToSearchBox.val().length === 0) {
                //console.log('reset event from box');
                dTable_filterColumnByDateRange (dTable, 1, '', '');
        // exit asap if date is invalid
        } else if ( isNaN(date_from) || isNaN(date_to) ) {
            //console.log('nan event from box')
            return;
        } else {
            //console.log('filter event from box');
            // we good? let's filter
            dTable_filterColumnByDateRange (dTable, 1, date_from, date_to);
        }
    });

    // date to
    dateRangeToSearchBox.change( function () {
        if (date_from === "" ||
            date_to === "" ||
            dateRangeFromSearchBox.val().length === 0 ||
            dateRangeToSearchBox.val().length === 0) {
                //console.log('reset event to box');
                dTable_filterColumnByDateRange (dTable, 1, '', '');
        // exit asap if date is invalid
        } else if ( isNaN( new Date( dateRangeToSearchBox.val() ).getTime() ) || isNaN(date_from) ) {
            //console.log('nan event to box')
            return;
        } else {
            //console.log('filter event from box');
            // we good? let's filter
            dTable_filterColumnByDateRange (dTable, 1, date_from, date_to);
        }
    });
    
    //date range reset
    dateRangeResetButton.click( function () {
        //console.log('reset event');
        // this part is crazy
        // don't worry I know it is
        $('#date_from_range_search').val('').promise().done( function () {
            $(this)
                .trigger('change')
                .prop('disabled', false);
            $('#date_to_range_search').val('').promise().done( function () {
                $(this)
                    .trigger('change')
                    .prop('disabled', false);
            });
        });
    });
});

// and now here is our worker function
// which the above dom ready code is calling:
/**
 * Filters a single column based on two date range values
 * @param {Object} data_table - jQuery html object instance of the table
 * @param {Integer} column_index - DataTables int value of date column to filter
 * @param {Integer} date_from - unix time stamp of start date to filter between
 * @param {Integer} date_to - unix time stamp of end date to filter between
 */
dTable_filterColumnByDateRange = function (data_table, column_index, date_from, date_to) {
    var rowValue_asTimeStamp = null;

    data_table
        .DataTable()
        .column()
        .data()
        .filter( function (value, index) {
            rowValue_asTimeStamp = new Date(value).getTime();

            // debug:
            //console.log('from', date_from);
            //console.log('to', date_to);
            //console.log('row', rowValue_asTimeStamp);
            //console.log('existing filters?', $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.length);
            if (date_to == null ||
                date_to == "" ||
                date_from == null ||
                date_from == "") {
                    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
                    var returnVal = true;
            } else {
                var returnVal = (rowValue_asTimeStamp >= date_from && rowValue_asTimeStamp <= date_to) ? true : false;
            }
        })
        .draw();

        // extend the filter API in the
        // most annoying way possible
        $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
            function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
                // built in reset?
                if (date_to == null ||
                    date_to == "" ||
                    date_from == null ||
                    date_from == "") {
                        //console.log(aData[column_index]);
                        return true;
                } else {
                    // debug:
                    //console.log('arg 1', (new Date(aData[column_index])).getTime());
                    //console.log('date from', date_from);
                    //console.log('date to', date_to);
                    //console.log('truth condition', ((new Date(aData[column_index])).getTime() > date_from && (new Date(aData[column_index])).getTime() < date_to));
                    /**
                     * THIS PART MAKES THE FILTER WORK IN SAFARI :)
                     */
                    var parsed = aData[column_index].replace(' ', 'T');
                    return ((new Date( parsed )).getTime() > date_from && (new Date( parsed )).getTime() < date_to);
                }
            }
        );
};
```

The above example is intended to work for columns that use a timestamp column value like: `<td>2016-08-05 19:14:00</td>`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker from your script and added some made up html table. I used as much of your code as possible but had to adjust some of your ids.
I'm not sure where along the way i made changes that finally got this working, but I guess its mainly related to your filter variables being not global.

```
// Date range filter
minDateFilter = "";
maxDateFilter = "";
```

instead of:

```
// Date range filter
var minDateFilter = "";
var maxDateFilter = "";
```

Have a look at this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTAmQRJHN1zVdzYJBKop?p=preview) with the full code which runs perfectly on FF 27.0.1 and find out for yourself.

Update:
Simplified the datepicker initialisition to this:

```
  $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    "onSelect": function(date) {
      minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }
  }).keyup(function() {
    minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
    oTable.fnDraw();
  });
```

This prevents the double assignement of the widget you have done in:

```
    $('#calender-from').click(function() {
        $("#datepicker_min").datepicker("show");
    });
```

and:

```
    $("#datepicker_min").datepicker({
        "onSelect": function(date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
```

Now it uses its native function to diplay an icon.

Maybe some browser are picky about this.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V31ufIfcUMEZHkuAE1VR?p=preview)

Comment: Appreciate the Plunker, still trying to figure out why it works and mine doesn't. Changing var that way didn't change my result, hrmm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script that worked for me.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex){
        var dateStart = parseDateValue($("#dateStart").val());
        var dateEnd = parseDateValue($("#dateEnd").val());


        var evalDate= parseDateValue(aData[5]);
        var evalDate1= parseDateValue(aData[6]);

        if ((evalDate >= dateStart && evalDate <= dateEnd)||(evalDate1 >= dateStart && evalDate1 <= dateEnd)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    });`
```